# Why is there an overload for String.Concat() which accepts one parameter in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string

Noticed this today when a patch was submitted with the following line:

```
lblCompletionTime.Text = String.Concat(trainingSkill.EndTime.ToLocalTime())
```

I can understand why the contributor used that syntax as above line concatenated two strings to form a multi-part date/time string.

Is there some hidden reason for having a single parameter overload of String.Concat() or was it included for "completeness" by the language designers.

I have replaced the line with:

```
lblCompletionTime.Text = trainingSkill.EndTime.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Which has the same output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String.Concat(Object) gives you String.Empty when you pass null; ToString would crash with a null pointer exception.

Comment: What's funny is that they could make ToString an extension method on Object so that even calling myObject.ToString() when myObject is null would work.

Comment: @Pierre: "can" is rarely a good reason without a supporting "should"

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it doesn't make much sense especially considering the fact that this is the implementation:

```
public static string Concat(object arg0)
{
        if (arg0 == null)
        {
                return Empty;
        }
        return arg0.ToString();
}
```

But it *does* validate that the argument isn't `null` so I guess that is something.  Still you aren't concatenating anything so I think that this method could have been called

```
String.ToStringSafe(Object obj) { }
```

or something similar to better express what the function actually does.

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN, [String.Concat(object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(VS.71).aspx)

> Creates the String representation of a
>   specified object.

Comment: Object.ToString() says more or less the same thing. "Returns a  String that represents the current  Object.". I had realised what it did, it was more the why that I was interested in.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the documentation of String.Concat(object), the only advantage I see is that it accepts a null and returns an empty string, which can be an advantage when compared with object.ToString() which would throw a NullReferenceException.
In your example it doesn't help because if trainingSkill.EndTime is null the program will break when invoking ToLocalTime.
I preffer your correction, but I think there's no need for passing CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as a parameter since it is the default  behaviour of DateTime.ToString()

Comment: The default behaviour seems a litle inconsitant particuarly on certain european installs .ToString will default to en-US, in fact FxCop will recommend replacing all instances of int.ToString(), DateTime.ToString() with the equavalant Overload that accepts an IFormatProvider.

Comment: According to documentation both DateTime.ToString() and CurrentInfo.CurrentCulture use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. So using DateTime.ToString(CurrentInfo.CurrentCulture) should always equal DateTime.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

In C# it may have little value (aside from the automatic empty string for a null value).

In .Net in general, I could this method signature being very useful in a functional language.

Comment: That is an interesting slant on the thought, I must admit I havn't looked at .NET based functional programming. What would stop you from using .ToString() in say F#?

Comment: For a single object, ToString would make sense; but if it's processing a list recursively (Head | Tail -- probably not F# syntax but you get the idea), it will call the same function on both -- one being a single object, the other a list, or null.

Comment: FWIW, this is just a gut instinct.  I have no proof that it actually works this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`String.Concat(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khca9w90.aspx) to convert an object to a string is the behavior that overload of the function was designed for.

> **String.Concat Method (Object)** 
>   Creates the  String representation of a specified object.